# Script python stops running for no reason after opening and closing a large number of files

Tags: python, python-3.x, large-files

I need to open several files, read them line by line and file them.
However, I have to analyze a large number of lines.
After about 240k lines the script seems to pause for no reason.

The code:

```py
for folder in os.listdir("Data"):
    for subfolder in os.listdir("Data/"+folder):
        with open("Data/"+folder+'/'+subfolder, "r", encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as f:
            for line in f:
                path = "Data/" + line[0] + "/"
                if not os.path.exists(path):
                    os.makedirs(path)
                with open(path + line[1] +".txt", "a", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f1:
                    f1.writelines(line)
                tested += 1
                print("folder: "+folder+", subfolder: "+subfolder+", tested: "+str(tested))
```

The console simply stops printing without stopping the script

Comment: Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Comment: @Adam Bernard how big is the file you want to read and how much RAM do you have on the pc you are using to run the script

Comment: The largest file was 3Gb for 16Gb of ram.
I corrected the problem.it was coming from a re.search() that was saturating.